# How to disable long press home button?

Tags: security

How can I disable or set password on long press home key button on smartphone?
As you know, with long press of home button, the running process (like sms, gallery, internet explorer, etc.) will be shown that can be kill them to make phone faster.

My question is how can I disable, change, lock or set password on this button to ask permission to show and kill apps, and prevent anyone to see and kill running apps.

My phone is Huawie and is not rooted.

Comment: Which model and which Android? Is the device rooted?

Comment: I'm aware of **Gravitybox** app which can disable or change the long press behavior, but it requires root access and **Xposed framework** installed. There can be non-root solutions which you can look on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be to *change* what the home button does instead of disabling it all together. You can use alternative launchers such as [Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.key) to change what the home button does. I was also able to find a free app that does it on its own [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eikatou0.appspot.home2shortcut&hl=en). I haven't used the latter but it seems useful.